# Data not being passed from listview into activity

Tags: android, string, android-activity

I have finally got my onListItemClick to work but now it seems as if the data I have set to be passed into the next activity does not go through but the activity still starts. My application doesn't crash or anything it just loads the activity but the data I had set to go with it doesn't seem to be there.  I have tried removing the scrollview but the data still doesn't seem to go through.

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {    

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;        

     final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
     final String TAG_QUESTION = "question";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
     final String TAG_ANSWERS = "Answers";
     final String TAG_ANSWER = "Answer";    
     final String TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT = "content";      
     final String TAG_QUERY = "query";

            JSONArray question = null;          
            android.widget.ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //setContentView(R.layout.listview);        
        questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 
        new LoadAllData().execute();
    }

    @Override   
    protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
         super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);  

         String Subject = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Subject)).getText().toString();
         String Content = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Content)).getText().toString();
         String ChosenAnswer = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ChosenAnswer)).getText().toString();


         Intent i = new Intent(ListView.this, SingleListItem.class);
         i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
         i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, Content);
         i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, ChosenAnswer);
         startActivity(i);

            }     


    class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        private Dialog pDialog;
        @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ProgressDialog pDialog; 
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                Intent in = getIntent();
                String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "http://example.com";
                JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                try {
                    //question = json.getJSONArray(TAG_QUESTION);


                    JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

                    for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


                    String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                    String NumAnswers = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS);
                    String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                    String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                    //JSONArray Answers = question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS).getJSONArray(TAG_ANSWER);


                    //JSONObject Answer = Answers.getJSONObject(0);

                    //String Content = Answer.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);

                               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS, NumAnswers);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, Content);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, ChosenAnswer);

                               questionList.add(map);


                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                return TAG_QUESTION    ; 



        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) {
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                        R.layout.listelements,
                        new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS }, new int[] {
                        R.id.Subject, R.id.NumAnswers });

                setListAdapter(adapter); 


        }}}
```

SingleListItem Activity:

```
public class SingleListItem extends Activity {

    TextView title;
    TextView question;
    TextView bestanswer;
    TextView subject;
    TextView content;
    TextView chosenanswer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.singlelistitem);

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Title1);
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question1);
    bestanswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BestAnswer1);
    subject = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Subject1);
    content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Content1);
    chosenanswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ChosenAnswer1);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String Subject = i.getStringExtra("TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT");
    String Content = i.getStringExtra("TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT");
    String ChosenAnswer = i.getStringExtra("TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER");
    subject.setText(Subject);
    content.setText(Content);
    chosenanswer.setText(ChosenAnswer);

    }
}
```

singlelistitem.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Subject1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Question1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Question:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Content1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/BestAnswer1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Best Answer:" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ChosenAnswer1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your keys are not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your keys are not the same.

You have this

```
i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
```

and `TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT` is "Subject"

```
final String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";
```

Your get part is

```
String Subject = i.getStringExtra("TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT"); // keys do not match
// must be "Subject"
```

Change it to below. Keys must match

```
String Subject = i.getStringExtra("Subject");
String Content = i.getStringExtra("Content");
String ChosenAnswer = i.getStringExtra("ChosenAnswer");
```

Comment: thanks for all your help I should of this seen this myself. Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you how I can pass `TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";` and `String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";` without populating these string into my listview.  The reason I ask this is because when I click on the item I want the only string that displays in the other activity is `String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";` and this is because `Subject` is the only string that I want to pass that has been populated into the listview. Those two other string contain data I just need to know how to pass them without having to populate them into the listview.

Comment: @BobLast you can pass the values without populating in listview. your hashmap has the data just use the same and pass the values using intent

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `same keys` for both sending and receiving. Some of the keys in your `sending activity doesn't match with the keys` in receiving activity.

**For Sending:**

```
map.put("Question", Subject);
map.put("NumAnswer", NumAnswers);
map.put("content", Content);
map.put("chosenAnswer", ChosenAnswer);
```

**For Receiving:**

```
String Subject = question.getString("Question");
String NumAnswers = question.getString("NumAnswer");
String ChosenAnswer = question.getString("chosenAnswer");
String Content = question.getString("content");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've named the extras, e.g., "Subject" in your listview activity, then reference them differently in the single item activity:

```
String Subject = i.getStringExtra("TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT");
```

Might look into that.